# Uncertainty in estimating a polygon area in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, precision

I have 2 methods to compute the area of a polygon:

1. Using the dedicated method: `ee.Feature.area()`
2. Summing the area of each pixels of an image reduced to the polygon using `ee.Image.reduceRegion()`
   Method 1 is obviously much more straight forward but method 2 is useful if you are not interested only about the polygon area but in the reduction of a band that include the pixel areas (e.g. if you get an image of the fraction of tree coverage, the total area covered by tree in a given polygon is the sum over all pixels of the fraction of tree coverage multiplied by the pixel area).

I find that method 1 and 2 usually differ by about 0.5%. This is not much and most likely not to dominate as an uncertainty in most analysis, but still significantly higher than I would have expected. Especially that using method 2 with different scales give much more consistent results. **Any idea where the difference comes from?**

```js
var pa1 = ee.Image.pixelArea().reproject({crs:'EPSG:4326',scale:1})
var pa30 = ee.Image.pixelArea().reproject({crs:'EPSG:4326',scale:30})
var pa100 = ee.Image.pixelArea().reproject({crs:'EPSG:4326',scale:100})

var  f = ee.Feature({
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [[[20, 0], [20, -0.1], [19.9, -0.1], [19.9, 0]]]
  }
})

print('Area from method:', f.area())
print('Area from pixel sum (scale=1):', pa1.reduceRegion({reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(), geometry: f.geometry(), maxPixels: 1000000000}).getInfo()['area'])
print('Area from pixel sum (scale=30):', pa30.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.sum(), f.geometry()).getInfo()['area'])
print('Area from pixel sum (scale=100):', pa100.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.sum(), f.geometry()).getInfo()['area'])
```

Results from the code:

```
Area from method:
123643364.45103805

Area from pixel sum (scale=1):
123091222.47992136

Area from pixel sum (scale=30):
123090484.71821223

Area from pixel sum (scale=100):
123086593.00383721
```

Run the code on GEE: https://code.earthengine.google.com/b2b53d3e9e463956e690893474b89450

EDIT: QGIS calculate the area as: 123090660, indicating that the `ee.Feature.area()` would be off.